# xarray.Dataset.to_zarr: docs for “Appending to existing Zarr stores”?

Tags: python, python-xarray, zarr

In the description of the '`region`' argument to `xarray.Dataset.to_zarr` the last sentence states: *`See “Appending to existing Zarr stores” in the reference documentation for full details`*.  I have not been able to find this reference in the reference docs or anywhere else- I'm starting to suspect that it doesn't exist.  Can anyone point me to a location for this alleged documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation is very clear on that (maybe it could benefit from a hyperlink).

But if you copy *"Appending to existing Zarr stores"* and paste it into the search bar on the top left (*Search docs*) you should easily arrive at the section titled [Appending to existing Zarr stores](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/io.html?appending-to-existing-zarr-stores#appending-to-existing-zarr-stores), which is the one you are looking for.

---

### Update 2024

The section about updating / modifying zarr stores in the docs is now called [modifying existing zarr stores](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/io.html#modifying-existing-zarr-stores). (thanks @Thomas)